# Decorator pattern: enhanced design?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator, composition

I'm reading and example provided in "Head first design patterns book" about decoration pattern.

I have noticed 2 things:

1. if you will need to remove a decorator from the stack of the wrapped decorators, you will have to iterate one by one through the component reference, which is O(n) complexity.
2. Conceptually I find it wrong to wrap (encapsulate) the base component in to the decorator object. It should be reversed; the component object should encapsulate the decorating objects.

I'm new to design patterns, and there is high probability that I'm wrong. Please explain to me what is specifically wrong with the way I think so I can learn.

I have created a different design, which solves the problems that I have mentioned. Maybe they add new problems; please feel free to point out the issues.

Here is the UML Diagram of the suggestion:

[image: UML Diagram of the suggestion]

Basically what I did is that I have created a dictionary in the Component class which saves which decorators have been added, and made the Decorator abstract class not inherit from the component yet from Interface (so the component abstract class).

In this way, we can remove any decoration we want with O(1) complexity, and it is more logically constructed in the way that the component wraps the decorator, not the vice versa.

I understand that maybe I didn't noticed some advantage of the original Decorator pattern design. Please advice me.

Here is my code [url](https://github.com/Talxolenia/Design-Patterns).

**Edit:**

An example of when a customer will need to remove a decorator:

say for example the customer is choosing the condiments, he is adding whip, removing caramel, see each time how the total price vary, based on what the client is choosing to be added as a decorator.

Comment: First, can you elaborate about why you think it would be useful to remove a decorator dynamically in the StarBuzz case? (I can imagine a reason, but your question would be better if you were explicit). Second, what kind of *n* do you think is typical in the StarBuzz scenario? I'm guessing max(n) is probably 20, so iterating over that many iterators would not likely be an issue with a modern computer.

Comment: I have included the example in the main question which explains when a customer will need to remove a decorator, but I think I started to see your point, maximum amount of a decorators that could be warped is 20, so yes, it's perfectly logical to use O(n) solution for this amount, please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. if you will need to remove a decorator from the stack of the wrapped decorators, you will have to iterate one by one through the component reference, which is O(n) complexity.

It's true that removing decorators is theoretically more complex when they're wrapped. However, you need to consider what is a likely *n*. I'm going to guess for the decorator pattern as it was proposed, there are probably a small (max(*n*) == 20) iterators. Iterating over that many would not be a practical problem.

> 2. Conceptually I find it wrong to wrap (encapsulate) the base component in to the decorator object. It should be reversed; the component object should encapsulate the decorating objects.

The Decorator pattern seeks to add functionality (via concrete decorators) without having to modify the component class. In some cases, a Component can't be changed (e.g., it comes from a standard library). With the approach you propose, the Component would have to be modified to encapsulate its decorators. This is not the intention of Decorator.

In the [original GoF book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), the design patterns have clear definitions of the *problem* they solve, and the *consequences* (which are not all positive!) of the design pattern. In line with your complexity point (removing decorators), the authors mentioned this consequence:

> 4. *Lots of little objects.* A design that uses Decorator often results in systems composed of lots of little objects that all look alike. The objects differ only in the way they are interconnected, not in their class or in the value of their variables. Although these systems are easy to customize by those who understand them, they can be hard to learn and debug.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why would you need to "remove a decorator from the stack of the warped decorators"? What does this mean? I think you're confusing two different concepts, the decorator pattern and stacks. The first is a design pattern in object-oriented programming, the latter is a data structure.
2. The decorator pattern exists so that new functionality can be added to a base component without the need to redefine the components that use/are dependent on it. That's why the decorator component "encapsulates" the base component, so that it can then use whatever functionalities it contains, while adding others required. If the base component encapsulated the decorator components, how would you reference a functionality present in any given one of them? Following you example, imagine I call `Mocca.GetCost()`. If it's not overriden nor redefined, `CondimentDecorated.GetCost()` will be called, which in turn, I imagine, considering what you're trying to do, will call `Beverage.GetCost()`. What will this method do? Iterate over the dictionary to look for which decorator method to call? This doesn't make sense, as, in calling `CondimentDecorated.GetCost()` you'll only be calling `Beverage.GetCost()` again. How will all this work if you can, as you said, "remove any decoration you want" from the decorators dictionary? What will be the behaviour then, when you call `Mocca.GetCost()`?

It's not that what you're trying to do isn't possible, and it's great to question why something is the way it is. But there's just a lot OOP misconceptions and violations here. Meaning, question not only how things could be made better, but also why they are done the way they are.

Comment: answering your questions:
1. say for example the customer is choosing the condiments, he is adding whip, removing caramel, see each time how the total price vary, based on what the client is choosing to be added as a decorator.
2.No I'm not confusing stacks in data structures and decorator pattern, I used the word "stack" because I started seeing that each new decorating object is siting on top of the old object, maybe it is more like linked list.
3.I can reference a functionality present in any given one of them, by iterating through the dictionary, and calling the interface method.

Comment: in my UML diagram, the Decorator Abstract class is not inheriting from the Component Abstract class yet the both inherit from ICost interface which is the common associations between the 2 classes.
Finally instead of having a reference to the component object in the decorator object, it holds a dictionary of decorators in the component object

Comment: `what the client is choosing to be added as a decorator` I don't understand this sentence. `each new decorating object is siting on top of the old object` you mean each decorator instance can reference an instance of the base component? If so, yes, how else would you reference its functionalities? `calling the interface method` calling the interface method means calling the method of the class that implements the interface. So, how would all this work?

Comment: Isaac , please review my code if you want(or even if you have time), and then tell me if it is a lot of OOP violation, I think I couldn't explain correctly what I wanted to say.

Comment: One OOPS violation which I perceive is your design is violating Single Responsibility Principle. Beverage class will have its own business logic (what responsibility it should handle), apart from this proposed design also assigning additional responsibility of maintaining decorators, iterating through them and calculate cost. I'll encourage you to look at Head First implementation of Decorator pattern and reply back how is it handling SRP. 
I really appreciate your way of learning. Keep it up and way to go.